# how to remove option from a selectbox

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, triggers

I am trying to remove the last 2 option from the selectbox if room2 and room4 is selected. I couldn't make it work. Any ideas?
Also on the 3rd selectbox if option **More** is selected I want **7 days** automatically to be selected and show an alert: contact office for long stay.

```js
    $('#calculator_accomodation').change(function(){
      if($(this).val() == 'ROOM2' || $(this).val() == 'ROOM4' ){ 

    $("#cost_calculator_person").option("5").remove();
    $("#cost_calculator_person").option("6").remove();
    alert('room2 is triggered')
      }
    });
    $('#cost_calculator_days').change(function(){
      if($(this).val() == 'More' ) { 
    alert('Contact office for long stay');
    // code to select '7' goes here
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="calculator_accomodation" name="calculator_accomodation">
    <option value="ROOM1">ROOM ONE</option>
    <option value="ROOM2">ROOM TWO</option>
    <option value="ROOM3">ROOM TREE</option>
    <option value="ROOM4">ROOM FOUR</option>
    <option value="ROOM5">ROOM FIVE</option>
    <option value="ROOM6">ROOM SIX</option>
    <option value="ROOM7">ROOM SEVEN</option>
    <option value="ROOM8">ROOM EIGHT</option>
    </select>
    <select id="cost_calculator_person" name="cost_calculator_person">
    <option value="1">1 PERSON</option>
    <option value="2">2 PEOPLE</option>
    <option value="3">3 PEOPLE</option>
    <option value="4">4 PEOPLE</option>
    <option value="5">5 PEOPLE</option>
    <option value="6">6 PEOPLE</option>
    </select>
<select name="cost_calculator_days" id="cost_calculator_days">
  <option selected="" value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="More">More</option>
                                        </select>
```

Comment: use this @Hijacker83 $("#cost_calculator_person option[value='5']").remove();

Comment: @hijacker83 for your days selection answer is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this for your next edited question**

```
$('#cost_calculator_days').change(function(){

      if($(this).val() == 'More' ) { 
    $("#cost_calculator_days option[value='7']").prop('selected',true);
    // code to select '7' goes here
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use slice.

```
$('#calculator_accomodation').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === 'ROOM2' || $(this).val() === 'ROOM4' ) { 

        $('#cost_calculator_person').find('option').slice(4, 6).remove();
        alert('room2 is triggered');
    }
});
```

Comment: also works. Thank you. why === is used but not ==         Any idea about how to select option '7' automatically when option 'More' is selected?

Comment: Using === js will match the type as well.

Comment: eg.
1 == '1' = true
1 === '1' = false
'1' === '1' = true.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method like `option()` in jQuery instead use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get the element with a certain attribute value.

```js
$('#calculator_accomodation').change(function() {
  if (this.value == 'ROOM2' || this.value == 'ROOM4') {
    $("#cost_calculator_person option[value='4'],#cost_calculator_person option[value='6']").remove();
    alert('room2 is triggered')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="calculator_accomodation" name="calculator_accomodation">
  <option value="ROOM1">ROOM ONE</option>
  <option value="ROOM2">ROOM TWO</option>
  <option value="ROOM3">ROOM TREE</option>
  <option value="ROOM4">ROOM FOUR</option>
  <option value="ROOM5">ROOM FIVE</option>
  <option value="ROOM6">ROOM SIX</option>
  <option value="ROOM7">ROOM SEVEN</option>
  <option value="ROOM8">ROOM EIGHT</option>
</select>
<select id="cost_calculator_person" name="cost_calculator_person">
  <option value="1">1 PERSON</option>
  <option value="2">2 PEOPLE</option>
  <option value="3">3 PEOPLE</option>
  <option value="4">4 PEOPLE</option>
  <option value="5">5 PEOPLE</option>
  <option value="6">6 PEOPLE</option>
</select>
```

Comment: $("#cost_calculator_person option[value= '5'],option[value= '6']").remove(); also works need not to write id again

Comment: Thank you very much. Sometimes the solution can be so simple:) You replied so quick before I was able to edit my post. On the 3rd selectbox, if option More is selected I also would like the value '7' to be automatically selected . I would appreciate if you can explain how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to somthing like this...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      $('#calculator_accomodation').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == 'ROOM2' || val == 'ROOM4' ) {
           $("#cost_calculator_person option[value='4']").css('display','none');
           $("#cost_calculator_person option[value='6']").css('display','none');
        } else {
           $("#cost_calculator_person option[value='4']").css('display','block');
           $("#cost_calculator_person option[value='6']").css('display','bolck');
        }
      });
      $('#cost_calculator_days').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'More' ) {
          alert('Contact office for long stay');
        }
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="calculator_accomodation" name="calculator_accomodation">
    <option value="ROOM1">ROOM ONE</option>
    <option value="ROOM2">ROOM TWO</option>
    <option value="ROOM3">ROOM TREE</option>
    <option value="ROOM4">ROOM FOUR</option>
    <option value="ROOM5">ROOM FIVE</option>
    <option value="ROOM6">ROOM SIX</option>
    <option value="ROOM7">ROOM SEVEN</option>
    <option value="ROOM8">ROOM EIGHT</option>
    </select>
    <select id="cost_calculator_person" name="cost_calculator_person">
    <option value="1">1 PERSON</option>
    <option value="2">2 PEOPLE</option>
    <option value="3">3 PEOPLE</option>
    <option value="4">4 PEOPLE</option>
    <option value="5">5 PEOPLE</option>
    <option value="6">6 PEOPLE</option>
    </select>
<select name="cost_calculator_days" id="cost_calculator_days">
  <option selected="" value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="More">More</option>
                                        </select>
```